# Count number of row from subquery which have data with groupby clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

This is my subquery:

```
select 
    count(a.ProcessDate),
    b.Market
from
    [dbo].[FileProcessLog] a
left join
    [dbo].[FileMaster] b on a.FileID = b.FileID
where 
    convert(date, a.ProcessDate) = convert(date, getdate()-2)
group by
    b.Market
```

Now I want number of rows of the result table but when I use below query I got error:

```
select count(*)
from
    (select count(a.ProcessDate), b.Market
     from [dbo].[FileProcessLog] a
     left join [dbo].[FileMaster] b on a.FileID = b.FileID
     where convert(date, a.ProcessDate) = convert(date, getdate()-2) 
     group by b.Market)
```

I have tried with alias name as well but it didn't work at all.

Please help finding a solution.

Comment: *"I got error"* And *what* was that error?

Comment: Also, get into the habit of using *good* aliases. "a" isn't for "File Process Log" and "B" isn't for "File Master"; *neither* of the objects even have the letters you've aliased them as in their name. `FPL` and `FM` would make *far* better aliases. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Larnu what is the error ?

Comment: I am getting error of incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: @AKHILOMAR is your original code working ?

Comment: can you add the code in your question that is working ?

Comment: Yeah that subquery is working fine when I run it separately on sql server

Comment: `select 
b.Market,
count(a.ProcessDate) as total
from [dbo].[FileProcessLog] a 
LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[FileMaster] b 
ON a.FileID = b.FileID 
where Convert(date, a.ProcessDate) = Convert(date, getdate()-2) 
GROUP BY b.Market ` does this work for you ?

Comment: Yes, Now I want number of rows from the result of this subquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249245/discussion-between-trillion-and-akhil-omar).

Comment: I don't know what the OP's error is, @trillion ...

Comment: looks strange the code below should work

Comment: The second query won't work, @trillion . The obvious errors are the derived table doesn't have a name, and neither does one of its column.

Comment: yes i am not even in the favor of subquery

Comment: @Larnu the solution i added works, its the cte

Comment: *"Yeah that subquery is working fine"* That's not a subquery, it's a derived table, @AKHILOMAR .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with main as (
select
b.Market,
count(a.ProcessDate) as total
from [dbo].[FileProcessLog] a
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FileMaster] b
ON a.FileID = b.FileID
where Convert(date, a.ProcessDate) = Convert(date, getdate()-2)
GROUP BY b.Market
) select count(*) as total_rows from main
```